# How to import Spark packages in AWS Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I would like to use the GrameFrames package, if I were to run pyspark locally I would use the command:

`~/hadoop/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/pyspark --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.6.0-spark2.3-s_2.11`

But how would I run a AWS Glue script with this package? I found nothing in the documentation...

Answer (score 3):

You can provide a path to extra libraries packaged into zip archives located in s3.

Please check out [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html#aws-glue-programming-python-libraries-job) doc for more details

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to using graphframes as follows:

Download the graphframes python library package file e.g. from [here](https://pypi.org/project/graphframes/#files). Unzip the `.tar.gz` and then re-archive to a `.zip`.  Put somewhere in s3 that your glue job has access to

When setting up your glue job:

- Make sure that your Python Library Path references the zip file
- For job parameters, you need `{"--conf": "spark.jars.packages=graphframes:graphframes:0.6.0-spark2.3-s_2.11"}`

Comment: Hi @RobinL, what if the package isn't a python module? Like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63912073/how-to-use-spark-packages-in-aws-glue

Answer (score 0):

Every one looking for an answer please read this comment..

In order to use an external package in AWS Glue pySpark or Python-shell:

1) 
Clone the repo from follwing url..
https://github.com/bhavintandel/py-packager/tree/master

> git clone git@github.com:bhavintandel/py-packager.git
>
> cd py-packager

2)
Add your required package under requirements.txt. For ex.,

pygeohash

Update the version and project name under setup.py. For ex.,

VERSION = "0.1.0"

PACKAGE_NAME = "dependencies"

3) Run the follwing "command1" to create .zip package for pyspark OR "command2" to create egg files for python-shell..

command1:

> sudo make build_zip

Command2:

> sudo make bdist_egg

Above commands will generate packae in dist folder.

4) Finally upload this pakcage from dist directory to S3 bucket. Then goto AWS Glue Job Console, edit job, find script libraries option, click on folder icon of "python library path" .. then select your s3 path.

finally use in your glue script:

import pygeohash as pgh

Done!

Answer (score 0):

Also set `--user-jars-firs: "true"` parameter in glue job.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use GraphFrames in an AWS Glue notebook by doing the following:

Get the appropriate jar file for the spark version you are running from https://spark-packages.org/package/graphframes/graphframes, e.g. graphframes-0.8.2-spark3.1-s_2.12.jar

Upload this jar file to an S3 bucket your notebook/job has access to.

Add the following settings to the top of your notebook before initializing the spark session:

```
%extra_jars s3://<mybucket>/graphframes-0.8.2-spark3.1-s_2.12.jar
%spark_conf spark.jars.packages=graphframes:graphframes-0.8.2-spark3.1-s_2.12
```

After you have initialized the spark session and have a spark context execute the following:

```
sc.addPyFile("s3://<mybucket>/graphframes-0.8.2-spark3.1-s_2.12.jar")
```

You can then import the graphframes package and use it as expected.

For some reason the addPyFile call is required and using %additional_python_modules instead does not work.