# How to use Spark packages in AWS Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, cassandra, aws-glue, spark-cassandra-connector

I'd like to use Datastax's [spark-cassandra-connector](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12/2.5.1) in AWS Glue. If I run pyspark locally, my command would look like

```
path/to/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit \
--conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=XXX \
--conf spark.cassandra.auth.username=XXX \
--conf spark.cassandra.auth.password=XXX \
--packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:2.5.1 \
~/my_script.py
```

How to run this script in Glue?

---

Things I've tried

- [How to import Spark packages in AWS Glue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53382166/how-to-import-spark-packages-in-aws-glue) It looks similar to my question. The accepted answer talks about adding a zipped python module as parameter. But the `spark-cassandra-connector` isn't a python module.
- (according to @alex's comment) put the SCC assembly in the Glue job's `Jar lib path`
  [image]

Error:

```
    File "/tmp/delta_on_s3_spark.py", line 75, in _write_df_to_cassandra
    df.write.format(format_).mode('append').options(table=table, keyspace=keyspace).save()
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 732, in save
    self._jwrite.save()
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o84.save.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.TableRef.<init>(TableRef.scala:4)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.DefaultSource$.TableRefAndOptions(DefaultSource.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:83)
......
```

- (according to @alex's comment) put `spark.jars.packages = com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:2.5.1` in the Glue job's `job parameter`

[image]

Error:

```
  File "/tmp/delta_on_s3_spark.py", line 75, in _write_df_to_cassandra
    df.write.format(format_).mode('append').options(table=table, keyspace=keyspace).save()
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 732, in save
    self._jwrite.save()
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o83.save.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:245)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
......
```

Comment: what is the problem with things that you have tried?

Comment: @AlexOtt I added the error log to my post. It seems like the spark connector library isn't properly loaded.

Comment: can you try the things that I described about packages, and SCC 3.0

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to use `--packages` or `--conf spark.jars.packages` with Maven coordinates, so Spark will correctly pull all necessary dependencies that are used by Spark Cassandra Connector (Java driver, etc.) - if you use `--jars` with only SCC jar, then your job will fail.

Starting with SCC 2.5.1, there is also a new artifact - [spark-cassandra-connector-assembly](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly) that includes all necessary dependencies.  With it you can avoid problems with conflicting dependencies, plus you can use it with `--jars` or with Glue job's Jar lib path.

P.S. With Spark 3.0 it's recommended to use SCC 3.0.0-beta, because of significant changes in internals of Spark SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the three suggestions. On the first one: using `--conf spark.jars.packages`, that's exactly what I tried. Am I not doing it right? Second one: use the assembly. I tried but didn't make difference. Third: use SCC-3.0.0. Glue only supports up to to Spark 2.4 at the moment. I updated my post to add more details to my attempts. Appreciate your thoughts!

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately I’m out of ideas - I’m not much familiar with Glue - my suggestions were mostly from typical problems with SCC... I’ll try with glue if I have time tomorrow. I know that SCC works with EMR without much problems

Comment: I'm not familiar with Glue either. And I think it's probably some stupid AWS settings that I didn't do right. Thanks though!

Comment: Turns out that the reason is AWS Glue only supports scala 2.11, but the SCC I used has scala 2.12